# How do I retrieve answers of the multichoice radio button in laravel?

Tags: laravel, forms, radio-button

I am developing a multi choice questionaire. I want to get the answered question of the student. How do I go about it?

My Code

```
<div class="car card-body" style="border: #d3d3d3 1px solid; padding: 2rem">
  1. &nbsp; Don&#039;t do tath <br />
   <div style="padding-top: 1rem;">
   <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value=2TpZL1kJjUj7XNysyqSk">
   <input type="radio" name="option[1]" id="" style="display:inline"
                          value="a">
  1. Computer is an electronic device
       <br />
     <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="2TpZL1kJjUj7XNysyqSk">
     <input type="radio" name="option[1]" id="" style="display:inline"
                            value="b">Computer is human
                        <br />
      <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="2TpZL1kJjUj7XNysyqSk">
      <input type="radio" name="option[1]" id="" style="display:inline"
                            value="c">in hime i came
                        <br />
                                                </div>
                </div>
                                    <br />
                <div class="car card-body" style="border: #d3d3d3 1px solid; padding: 2rem">
  2. &nbsp; What is Web Development <br />
  <div style="padding-top: 1rem;">
  <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="8qbpQJ2ob4RvlcEJzszY">
  <input type="radio" name="option[2]" id="" style="display:inline" value="a">development involved database management
      <br />
  <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="8qbpQJ2ob4RvlcEJzszY">
  <input type="radio" name="option[2]" id="" style="display:inline"
                            value="b">
  web development involves the design of the law
                        <br />
  <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="8qbpQJ2ob4RvlcEJzszY">
  <input type="radio" name="option[2]" id="" style="display:inline"
                            value="c">Web store is the absolute beginer
                        <br />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group mt-3">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
 </div>
```

Controller

```
public function submitExam(Request $request){
    $myOption = $request->get('option');
    $optioncount =  count($myOption);
    for($i=1; $i<$optioncount + 1; $i++){
        echo $request->get("question_id");
        echo $myOption[$i]. "<br />";   
       $option = Options::where('question_id', $question)->value('answer');
      if($myOption[$i] == $option){
          echo "Good";
      }
    }
}
```

I want to select from option where question id is the same and compare it the value of the selected radio button but I only get the question id of the first question. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: @KurtFriars For each question. All the option has the same name. I have updated my question.

Comment: You need to add substantially more detail to this question where do you "want to get the answered question on the student".

Comment: From what you have put in your question, start here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Comment: @KurtFriars I have looked at it and I get the values but it does not solve my problem. I have updated my question can you look at it an help. Thanks

Comment: Please post the output of dd($request->input()); from the top of your controller method.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved it.

```
<div class="car card-body" style="border: #d3d3d3 1px solid; padding: 2rem">
 <div style="padding-top: 1rem;">
  <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value=2TpZL1kJjUj7XNysyqSk">
    <input type="radio" name="option[1]" id="" style="display:inline" value="a">
     1. Computer is an electronic device
      <br />
      <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="2TpZL1kJjUj7XNysyqSk">
    a. <input type="radio" name="option[1]" id="" style="display:inline" value="b">Computer is human
       <br />
       <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="2TpZL1kJjUj7XNysyqSk">
       <br />
    b.  <input type="radio" name="option[1]" id="" style="display:inline" value="c">computer is 
      </div>
    </div>
```

Controller

```
        $score = 0;
 foreach ($request->input('question_id', []) as $key => $question) {

        $answer = $request->input('option.'.$question);
        $correctAnswer = Questions::where('question_id', $question)->value('answer');
        if ($correctAnswer == $answer) {
            $score++;
        }
   }
```

source

https://github.com/imran1234567/Online-Examination-System/blob/master/resources/views/tests/create.blade.php

https://github.com/imran1234567/Online-Examination-System/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/TestsController.php